# iOS Swift Firebase SDK Import issue

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, cocoapods

I've been trying to import Firebase into my project. I've done this several times in other projects without any issues.  When I import Firebase in AppDelegate and call FirebaseApp.configure() everything is fine, no problem.

Issue came up when I imported Firebase/Database in other part of the project, suddenly in AppDelegate there is an error with no such a module Firebase and I can't call FirebaseApp.configure().

This happens also with other firebase modules imported e.g. Remote Config.

These are the pods I am importing

```
pod 'Firebase/RemoteConfig'
pod 'Firebase/Database'
```

The only solution I found was to make Objective C wrapper which imports Firebase modules inside implementation file so there is no public import of another Firebase modules.

Comment: show the output of pod update

Answer (score 0):

Add `use_frameworks` to your Podfile

**Example**

```
  platform :ios, "9.0"
  # Uncomment the next line if you're using Swift or would like to use dynamic frameworks
    use_frameworks!

    target 'yourprojectTarget' do
     pod 'Firebase'
    end
```

**Then**

```
pod install --no-repo-update
```

Comment: I have the use_frameworks! line in my podfile from start

Comment: if you have used use_frameworks then remove import line it will automatically imported to your swift project.

Comment: No it wont import, sameway i have to import Snapkit, FBSDK etc.. otherwise frameworks are not visible